# Not sending email content to webhooks in pipedream

Tags: python, triggers, webhooks, pipedream

I used the following code in pipedream to send the received email content via webhook.
In the code below, the content of the email is sent to the Discord webhook, but it is not sent to the webhooks that I have placed in the webhook_urls section.
I first used email as a trigger and then put the code in the HTTP / Webhook API in Python.
In addition, after the test, I did not receive any error, but the webhooks that I put in the webhook_urls section are not sent.
I don't know which part of the code has a problem. Please help me if anyone knows where the problem is.
Thank you for your attention and help.

```js
import re
import json
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter, Retry
from datetime import datetime

# =====================================
# SETTING
# =====================================

webhook_urls = [
  r"https://www.example.com/webhook-1/",
  r"https://www.example.com/webhook-2/",
]

# vv for logging (fill in the webhook URL if you need)
discord_webhook_url = r"https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xxxxx"

# 4 = info, ok, warning, error
# 3 = ok, warning, error
# 2 = warning, error
# 1 = error only
# 0 = OFF
log_level = 4



# =====================================
# CODE
# =====================================

show_welcome_msg = False

url_regex = "https?://([A-Za-z_0-9.-]+).*"

dc_embeds_sample = [{
    "type":"rich",
    "title": "",
    "description": "",
    "color": 5533306,
    "footer": {
        "text": "",
        "icon_url": ""
      },
    }]

class log:
    def info(payload):
        if (log_level < 4 or log_level < 0):
            return
        embeds = dc_embeds_sample.copy()
        embeds[0]["title"] = "INFO"
        embeds[0]["description"] = payload
        embeds[0]["color"] = 5533306
        send_msg_to_dc("", embeds)

    def ok(payload:str):
        if (log_level < 3 or log_level < 0):
            return
        embeds = dc_embeds_sample.copy()
        embeds[0]["title"] = "OK"
        embeds[0]["description"] = payload
        embeds[0]["color"] = 5763719
        send_msg_to_dc("", embeds)

    def warning(payload:str):
        if (log_level < 2 or log_level < 0):
            return
        embeds = dc_embeds_sample.copy()
        embeds[0]["title"] = "WARNING"
        embeds[0]["description"] = payload
        embeds[0]["color"] = 16776960
        send_msg_to_dc("", embeds)

    def error(payload:str):
        if (log_level < 1 or log_level < 0):
            return
        embeds = dc_embeds_sample.copy()
        embeds[0]["title"] = "ERROR"
        embeds[0]["description"] = payload
        embeds[0]["color"] = 15548997
        send_msg_to_dc("", embeds)

def extract_domain_name(url:str):
    m = re.search(url_regex, url)
    if m:
        return m.group(1)
    return None

def post_request(webhook_url:str, payload:str or json, auto_json_dumps:bool = True):
    headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.64 Safari/537.11"
        }
    data = json.dumps(payload) if auto_json_dumps else payload
    # start a session
    session = requests.Session()
    # set retry policy
    retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    # add adapter to session
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)
    # send request
    response = session.post(webhook_url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return response

def send_msg_to_dc(message, embeds=None):
    if (len(discord_webhook_url.strip()) == 0):
        return # empty URL
    if extract_domain_name(discord_webhook_url) is None:
        print("Invalid Discord Webhook URL")
        return
    payload = json.dumps({'content': f"{message}", "embeds":embeds} )
    post_request(discord_webhook_url, payload, False)

def send_webhook(payload:str):
    # load json
    try:
        payload = json.loads(payload)
    except ValueError as err:
        pass
    # loop
    for webhook_url in webhook_urls:
        domain = extract_domain_name(webhook_url)
        if domain is None:
            log.warning(f"Send webhook failed.\nReason: invalid URL <{webhook_url}>\nContent: {payload}")
            continue
        currentTime = datetime.now()
        response = post_request(webhook_url, payload)
        time_used = (datetime.now()-currentTime).total_seconds() * 1000
        if (response.status_code == 200):
            log.ok(f"Webhook Sent!\n\nProcess Time: {time_used}ms\nDomain: {domain}\nFull URL: {webhook_url}\nContent: {payload}")
        else:
            log.error(f"Send webhook failed.\nReason: {response.text}\nStatus: {response.status_code}\n\nDomain: {domain}\nFull URL: {webhook_url}\nContent: {payload}")


def handler(pd: "pipedream"):
    global show_welcome_msg
    if not show_welcome_msg:
        log.info("You are GOOD to go!\n\n")
        show_welcome_msg = True
        
    # extract data from previous steps
    content = pd.steps["trigger"]["event"]["body"]["text"]
    from_email = pd.steps["trigger"]["event"]["headers"]["from"]["value"][0]["address"]
    
    if from_email in ["noreply@tradingview.com"]:
        send_webhook(content)
```